# Retrieving employee email addresses via Quickbooks API

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to create a list of employees and their email addresses using the Quickbooks API. I'm using the following API call:

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/123/query?query=SELECT * FROM Employee
```

This returns a lot of great information, but not the email address. According to the [docs](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Employee), it should be returned as `PrimaryEmailAddr`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that if you create a user in QuickBooks and attach that user to an existing employee, the email address used by the user does not automatically propagate to the employee record. So, my new question is this: is there any way to get the email addresses of users that are associated with a company (regardless of whether or not they are employees)?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by creating 'user' and associating it to an existing employee ? Are you creating it from UI ? I've queried against my qbo account and I see that PrimaryEmailAddr is getting returned properly

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is if you invite some users(who are employees) to your company file using some email and that email address should come up when you query for employee entity. This use case is not supported. You need to explicitly mention the email address while creating an employee record, then only it will be retrieved on Read call.
There is no API to find the users associated with one company file.